# Exterior Algebra VS Torsion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, sheaf-theory

> Let $C$ be an irreducible and reduced rational curve, and $f: \mathbb P^1\rightarrow C$ be the normalization. If $\mathcal F$ is a coherent sheaf of rank $r$ over $C$, then I was wondering if we can conclude the following 
>   $$\wedge^r\left[(f^*\mathcal F)/\operatorname{Tor}\right] \cong \left[\wedge^r\left(f^*\mathcal F\right)\right]/\operatorname{Tor}.$$

It seems for me that this is just a question in commutative algebra, but I do not find any reference for this. Do anyone have some ideas or comments?

Thank you.

Comment: What does "/Tor" mean?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I mean the quotient by torsion subsheaf.

Comment: I wonder if the geometric background is just getting in the way here.

Comment: @Hoot Yes, may be we just need to consider $\mathcal F$ as a coherent sheaf over $\mathbb P^1$. Now the question is to ask if the exterior algebra commutes with the quotient by torsion.